# How to avoid memory leak in my method?

Tags: c++

For my home work I need to write String object in C++.

One of the methods is

```
void concatenate(String *s)
```

But when I check my object with Valgrind, there is a memory leak in my code. Here is method:

```
// add s's str to this _str
void String::concatenate(String *s)
{
  char * conc;
  int conc_size, i, j;

  conc_size = _len + s->_len;

  conc = new char[conc_size];  // line 39

  for (i = 0; i < _len; i++)
    conc[i] = _str[i];

  for (j = 0; i < conc_size || j < s->_len; i++, j++)
    conc[i] = s->_str[j];

  _str = conc;   // i'm assuming the problem is here
  _len = conc_size;
}
```

Here is Valgrind message:

```
==4706== 3 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 9
==4706==    at 0x100024679: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:266)
==4706==    by 0x10007BF04: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib)
==4706==    by 0x10007BF96: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib)
==4706==    by 0x100000E7E: String::concatenate(String*) (String.cpp:39)
==4706==    by 0x100001479: main (main.cpp:27)
```

Works with `delete [] _str;` and changed constructors:

```
// the empty string.
String::String()
{
    _len = 1;

    _str = new char[_len];
    assert(_str);
    _str[0] = '\0';
}

// store s string in this
String::String(char *s)
{
    _len = 0;

    int i = 0;
    while(s[i] != '\0')
    {
        _len++;
        i++;
    }

    _str = new char[_len];
    assert(_str);

    for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0' && i < _len; i++)
        _str[i] = s[i];

}
```

Comment: You are right. You forgot to `delete [] _str;` before assigning `conc` to it

Comment: Who gives homework to implement something which is already aptly solved with `std::string`?

Comment: Unrelated side note: shouldn't the condition in the second loop be `i < conc_size && j < s->_len`? Besides, why don't you just use `std::copy`?

Comment: @JohnLeidegren: my teacher :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not dealocating the previous contents of your member `_str`. I'm assuming that's also a `char*`. So when you're telling `_str` to point elsewhere, the memory it previously pointed to will be unacessible.

```
delete[] _str;
_str = conc;
```

Comment: @user1090944 In another answer, it's suggested that you check `_str != NULL` before you call `delete`. That's bad advice, as `delete` on a null pointer is a no-op.

Comment: I did that, but Valgrind don't like it:

Comment: ==4957== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()

Comment: @user1090944 so the problem persists even with the `delete`? Can you post the new code, including the class declaration?

Comment: @user1090944 What was your problem exactly? Did you forget to initialize `_str` to a sensible value in all your constructors?

Comment: in the default constructor forgot to allocate memory for _str :)

Answer (score 1):

Before line

```
_str = conc;
```

Put

```
 delete[] _str;
```

Comment: delete is guaranteed to be safe on a null pointer, so the if (_str) is unnecessary

Comment: Well, you are right. It's possible to omit this checking. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, you are overwriting your internal pointer with a new one without deleting it.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you `delete[] _str`? This is dangling now.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is about right: You assign a new value to the `_str` pointer, but the memory that is allocated for it remains allocated. You need to call `delete[] _str;` right before that line to free the memory.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the `String::_str` is the `char *` hold the main pointer to data.

Therefore, you must consider an array delete to `_str` before you assign the conc.

```
delete[] _str;
_str = conc;
```

Addition, it's a good practice for you to consider the argument of the concatenate method like `concatenate(const String &)`.